# Adding a text label in front of dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a label in front of a select box, I have set the div tag that contains both element to be "inline-block". But, the span is still on top of the select box.

```
<div class="unselected-field" style="display: inline-block;" id="selectCountry">
    <span>test</span><select id="countrySelect" name="countrySelect"></select>
</div>
```

Any ideas ? I am on Chrome...

Comment: Could it be that my parent html elements have some sort of css that override my default style ?

Comment: do you have a live site to look at? would be handy to see all the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the `<select>`'s width plus the `<span>`'s width is greater than the containing `<div>`, the `<select>` will be forced to go below the `<span>` instead of being beside it. also, `<select>`'s width relies on the text that it contains, so it can have a varying width unless you give it a static width.

Answer (score 16):

One option would be to just `disable` the first selected option:

```
<select id="countrySelect" name="countrySelect">
  <option  disabled selected>Select Your Country:</option>
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option>France</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 12):

I usually wrap the label around the input:

```
<div class="unselected-field" style="display: inline-block;" id="selectCountry">
    <label>Test:<select id="countrySelect" name="countrySelect">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code in `unselected-field` because I was able to get this to display properly in Chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/tVT67/

In fact, I can even remove the `inline-block` and it still works  http://jsfiddle.net/H3GDN/

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/KG9hL/1/

Unless of course the containing `div`s width is less than the combined width of the `label` and `select` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/74bRX/

Answer (score 0):

This works like charm:

```
<select id="countrySelect" name="countrySelect">
  <option  disabled selected style="display:none">Select Your Country:</option>
  <option>India</option>
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>UK</option>
</select>
```